# Minecraft 1.6.4 World fails to load or generate

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

Whenever I go to load or generate a world the game decides to crap out and go into a dirt background.

Here is the client log:http://pastebin.com/LTKYMUGF

Here is the Forge Moadloader Client 0 just in case: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0gjm1htwyns8y0/Forge%20Moadler%20Error%20log.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft crashes with exit code -805306369](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259688/minecraft-crashes-with-exit-code-805306369)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out how to fix my problem at least. Seems minecraft was throwing a permgen exception. I have 8 gigs of ram and in edit profile under JVM I added this
-Xmx6G -Xms3G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something wrong happened when downloading the patch... Here's what I want you to do:

**(Back up your saves before you follow my directions. If you don't know how, the steps are in the instructions, but I'm not responsible if there's a mistake.)**

Download a new client from the Minecraft [website](https://minecraft.net/download). Then, I want you to follow these directions:

**Windows 7:**

1. Press start, type in %appdata% in the search bar, and press enter. A folder should pop up.
2. Navigate your way to .minecraft/saves/. Copy everything in that folder to another location. Your desktop, for instance.
3. Now, go back up the folders and delete the .minecraft folder. Empty your recycle bin.
4. Open up the Minecraft Launcher and log in. If you followed directions correctly, it should automatically update.
5. Now, close Minecraft and copy the stuff you copied to your desktop back into .minecraft/saves/
   Open Minecraft. Enjoy!

**Windows XP:**

6. Press start, click "run...", type in %appdata% in the run dialog, and press enter. A folder should pop up.
7. Navigate your way to .minecraft/saves/. Copy everything in that folder to another location. Your desktop, for instance.
8. Now, go back up the folders and delete the .minecraft folder. Empty your recycle bin.
9. Open up the Minecraft Launcher and log in. If you followed directions correctly, it should automatically update.
10. Now, close Minecraft and copy the stuff you copied to your desktop back into .minecraft/saves/
11. Open Minecraft. Enjoy!

This should give you a fresh install of Minecraft, and allow it to redownload the files that were corrupt. If it doesn't help, check your internet connection for packet loss, and try the steps again.

Comment: What you mean downloading the patch? I'm confused. I have reset the minecraft twice nothing happened.