# minecraft java exit code:-805306369

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everytime i try to play Minecraft Java on my computer, it crashes an comes up with this exit code: -805306369.
I've looked on the internet which said to allocate more RAM, and that it ran out of machine memory. So I did that an it didn't fix it. It keeps coming up with the same exit code.

It also says that the game I'm running is not responding, so I click the close button and it says "OpenJDK platform binary is not responding". Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft crashes with exit code -805306369](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259688/minecraft-crashes-with-exit-code-805306369)

Comment: Are there any mods in use? If so, that would make this off-topic.  But you can try removing the mods one by one and seeing if the issue resolves.  If it truly is an out of memory issue, then one of the mods you have installed could be leaking memory.

Comment: i do not believe i have installed any mods on the launcher. but thank you

Comment: Can you share us your PC's specs? and "...So I did that an it didn't fix it"... what exactly did you do?