# My Minecraft world stuck on loading dirt screen, the game crashed with code: -805306369 (Forge 1.19.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

My main Minecraft world can't be opened, it got stuck on a dirt screen without any loading indicator, then I had to force close Minecraft, and it reported the exit code: **-805306369**. I tried allocating more ram but it still failed. I can still run the other worlds using the same ram and mods configuration. anyone knows why?
Edit: Im playing on mods, but they still works on other worlds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft crashes with exit code -805306369](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259688/minecraft-crashes-with-exit-code-805306369)

Comment: Tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.